# Object to array conversion in Javascript,Django

Tags: javascript, django

I am sending a list from Views to Javascript using `render_to_response` in Django. But in Javascript i am getting the input as string and i am not able to convert it into array.

I need to splice the array to extract 3 different attributes.

1. data_positive
2. data_negative
3. data_neutral

**sentiment1** variable in views.py is my attribute where i am facing error.

```
def allexist(request):
response = {}
responseList = []
sentimentlist = []
dt = {}
fetchedhash = []
senti_vals = []
positive_list = []
negative_list = []
neutral_list = []
positive_vals = []
negative_vals = []
neutral_vals = []
sentiments = {}
d = Registered.objects.filter(id=userid).values('projectid', 'pname')

for x in d:
    date1 = Registered.objects.filter(projectid=x["projectid"]).values('startdate', 'enddate')
    for dt in date1:
        end = dt["startdate"]
        startd = dt["startdate"].date()
        startt = dt["startdate"].time()
        endd = dt["enddate"].date()
        endt = dt["enddate"].time()

        final = datetime.combine(startd, startt)
        final2 = final.replace(minute=00, second=00)
        finale = datetime.combine(endd, endt)
        finale2 = finale.replace(minute=00, second=00)

        word_list=[]
        e = Hashtagmodel.objects.filter(projectid=x["projectid"]).values('hashtaglist')

        for hashes in e:
            d = Tweetsmodel.objects.filter(UserID=userid, isoDate__range=(final2, finale2),
                                           TweetText__icontains=hashes["hashtaglist"]).values('isoDate').annotate(
                total=Count('TweetText')).order_by('isoDate')

            w = Tweetsmodel.objects.filter(UserID=userid, isoDate__range=(final2, finale2),
                                           TweetText__icontains=hashes["hashtaglist"]).values("TokeniZedString")

            s = Tweetsmodel.objects.filter(UserID=userid, isoDate__range=(final2, finale2),
                                           TweetText__icontains=hashes["hashtaglist"]).values('senti')

            # otherCount = 0
            created_at = []
            tweet_count = []
            response = {}

            for data in d:
                created_at.append(data['isoDate'])
                tweet_count.append(data["total"])
                # rowData = str(data['isoDate']) + "," + str(data['total'])

            response["date"] = created_at
            response["count"] = tweet_count

            responseList.append(response)
            for i in w:
                word_list.append(i["TokeniZedString"])
            concat_string = ','.join(word for word in word_list)

            concat_list = concat_string.split(",")
            counts = Counter(concat_list)
            word = []
            pingpong = 0
            for x in counts:
                pingpong = pingpong + 1
                if pingpong <= 1000:
                    word.append({"text": x, "size": counts[x]})
            jsonStr = json.dumps(word)

            for j in s:
                senti_vals.append(j["senti"])
            senti_string = ','.join(str(word) for word in senti_vals)
            senti_list = senti_string.split(",")
            counting = Counter(senti_list)
            positive = 0
            negative = 0
            neutral = 0
            for j in counting:
                if j == '4.0':
                    positive = counting[j]
                    positive_string = "\"positive\":" + str(counting[j])
                if j == '0.0':
                    negative = counting[j]
                    negative_string = "\"negative\":" + str(counting[j])
                if j == '1.0':
                    neutral = counting[j]
                    neutral_string = "\"neutral\":" + str(counting[j])

            positive_vals = Tweetsmodel.objects.filter(Q(senti="4.0") & Q(TweetText__icontains=hashes["hashtaglist"])).values(
                'TweetText')
            negative_vals = Tweetsmodel.objects.filter(Q(senti="0.0") & Q(TweetText__icontains=hashes["hashtaglist"])).values(
                'TweetText')
            neutral_vals = Tweetsmodel.objects.filter(senti="1.0", TweetText__icontains=hashes["hashtaglist"]).values('TweetText')
            positive_string = '-----#$$$%%%%____----'.join(str(word) for word in positive_vals)
            negative_string = '-----#$$$%%%%____----'.join(str(word) for word in negative_vals)
            neutral_string = '-----#$$$%%%%____----'.join(str(word) for word in neutral_vals)
            positive_list = positive_string.split("-----#$$$%%%%____----")
            negative_list = negative_string.split("-----#$$$%%%%____----")
            neutral_list = neutral_string[8:].split("-----#$$$%%%%____----")
            stupid = "\n" + "\n"
            positive_list = positive_list[:15]
            negative_list = negative_list[:15]
            neutral_list = neutral_list[:15]
            positive_list = [x + stupid for x in positive_list]
            negative_list = [x + stupid for x in negative_list]
            neutral_list = [x + stupid for x in neutral_list]

            # sentiments = [ {"positive": positive, "negative": negative, "neutral": neutral,"data_positive": positive_list, "data_negative": negative_list,"data_neutral":neutral_list}]

            sentiments = [{"positive":positive,"negative":negative,"neutral":neutral}]
            sentiments1=[{"data_positive": positive_list, "data_negative": negative_list,"data_neutral":neutral_list}]

            sentimentlist.append(sentiments)
            for alexa in sentimentlist:
                print("this is response of senti",alexa)

    return render_to_response("personal_anshul/allexist.html", {"responseList": responseList,"jsonStr": jsonStr ,"sentimentlist": sentimentlist,"jsonStr1":sentiments1,"e":e})
return render(request, "personal_anshul/allexist.html")
```

HTML file code snippet:  is passing **values(text)** of sentiment1 to my_var4

```
       <script>
var my_var = "{{ responseList }}";
var my_var2 = "{{ jsonStr }}";
var my_var3 = "{{ sentimentlist }}";
var my_var4 = "{{ jsonStr1 }}";
var my_var5 = "{{ e }}";

</script>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
    function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
//console.log(my_var4);
L=decodeHtml(my_var4);
console.log(typeof(L))
values = L.split(",/s")
console.log(values)
console.log(typeof(values))
```

Output of L: [image]

**Here is output of my_var4 variable on using console.log(my_var4)**

```
***

[{&#39;data_neutral&#39;: [&quot;ext&#39;: &#39;The 5 best deals on #Amazon right now will all make life easier /w60T7iCynr via @enquirer /ly0W1urLs4&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Reining in Big Data’s Robber\xa0Barons /EL3pu1VS0J #Facebook #Twitter #Amazon /8XiTEG0sPi&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39; /7WJqcDbzNp Promote #Amazon #Affiliate products AUTOMATICALLY with /2cDsaTmPbm #SeoExpert… /nVXBPXUQMm&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @Oldbrookender: Best Selling Action Adventure Series Set in Roman Britain\nFree on Kindle Unlimited\n#iartg #histfic #Rome\n#amazon #bestse…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @omghotels: View from The Shard &amp;amp; River Cruise for Two - Perfect Gift Experience For Two only £89. \n\n /x9lilcNsfF\n\n#Amazon #g…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @Oldbrookender: Best Selling Action Adventure Series Set in Roman Britain\nFree on Kindle Unlimited\n#iartg #histfic #Rome\n#amazon #bestse…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;#Apple, #Google, #Facebook, #Amazon, #Microsoft: Which #Tech Giant Will Fall First? /5hgwF71dDP&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @SusanneSpellman: #The Virus- Book 1  #Amazon /#ITunes /#B&amp;amp;N\n /9hB7mvKFZQ\n\nThe Virus #Book 2 (Coming Soon)\n /Vbcae…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @Dolors111068: LA MANSIÓN DE LOS NAVAS...  de @ja_gonzalez49 Una de las novelas #policíacas más leídas en #Amazon. Ambientada en los año…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @burginvecmo5389: ???????#?????????\n\n??#iTunes???\n10000?×30?\n\n??#Googleplay??? \n10000?×30?\n\n??#Amazon????\n10000?×30?\n\n??????\n\n??????\n?????????…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @mfoulk50: HOLY HUMANITY\nby James Foster\nThought provoking\nperspective after a\nlifetime in ministry\n#amazon\nRT, plz ;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Simplified Steps To Become An Expert #Amazon Seller @Hounddogdigital /qsmAIJTvKW /5wEJ6CuqKJ&#39;} 

&quot;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;&quot;nothing less than perfection&quot; WHEN I\&#39;M WEAK /OGLpCoexbJ #Amazon #Kindle #kindlebooks #Christianfiction&#39;} 

&#39;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @phonandroid: ?? #FnacDarty et #Google s’allient pour contrer le #HomePod et l’#AmazonEcho #GoogleHome &amp;gt; /zYAjATgVq7 ;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;?[???????!!]GOOD TIMES A COLLECTION OF AMERICAN STANDARDS  #????? #LaserDisc ????#amazon ???!!… /8JMkgjIjCn&#39;} 

&quot;], &#39;data_negative&#39;: [&quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;???????????????????????????????????????? ???? /qxErKTaO8c #books #amazon&#39;} 

&quot;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;4.3 Stars: Women&#39;s Plus Size 711 Skinny  Ankle Jeans for $30. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /0YV0NYeXrg&quot;} 

&#39;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;#UK 26% off: Samsung  Level Active Wireless Headphone Black for £59.44. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal… /q3gxh6FSu9&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Philo to Add #Apple TV, Android, and #Amazon Fire TV Support @ Cord Cutters News, LLC .. #?????_??????? /IOgmiDMWBr&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39; /14rCHPGkat\n #Multicultural #Steamy #Romance #Suspense #Contemporary #Free #Book #Kindle #review #amazon /nyOduXxtYT&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @mangahack: ?Android???????????\n?????10?? #Amazon???? 500??????????\n????&amp;amp;RT???????????????? ?5/6(?)23:59??\n\n??????????????????????DL?????…&#39;} 

&quot;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;4.4 Stars: Bcbgmax Azria Women&#39;s  Dara V-neck Dress for $92. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /CddVycgV4k&quot;} 

&#39;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Return to Cedar Hill \n /ECoYAEDBJS  #Free #Book #Kindle #review #amazon #christianfiction #Siblings,… /xpXnczKZpY&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Return to Cedar Hill \n /XkWAarlRSR  #Free #Book #Kindle #review #amazon #christianfiction #Siblings,… /YptXML70RR&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @corrigenda_es: #DesdeElTragaluz, de @Marie_N_Vianco\n /DGXDhmpzPE    \n#Amazon #thriller #novela\nA veces el lugar más inesper…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;4.7 Stars: Pat  The Patriot Expandable Bangle Bracelet for $32. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /lESdb5zcGQ&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @SometimesYouDie: Trump Is Right /g8Z0hLkuUf #USPS #Bezos #Amazon #MAGA @cvpayne&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;??????? (???????) /RxrIgRqVTB #Amazon&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;#starvingartist /IcSYAiuXPI #socialmediamarketing #blog #blogging #asmsg #IARTG #IAN1 #Amazon #AmWriting #firebirdslight&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;????????????? /2UkRy4RLur #Amazon&#39;} 

&quot;], &#39;data_positive&#39;: [&quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @AuthorEllie: The Dead Wake Anthology #Amazon /d5Rv67z5rl  ?????? Are you brave enough? Ten stories to disable you!  #zombies…&#39;} 

&quot;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;RT @W_Angels_Wings: Available on #Amazon ~ With Angel&#39;s Wings\n /t3EG8ScQre\n#AwardWinner #memoir #specialneeds #parenting #Kindle…&quot;} 

&#39;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;#USA Deals: Women&#39;s Printed  Inverted Pleat Dress for $38. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /zn1Lco1GwC&quot;} 

&#39;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;#Sondage #ecommerce : Pour vos achats en ligne, quel canal privilégiez vous ?\nLe géant américain #Amazon ? Le franç… /06MCMcBJ23&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;(Actualitté) Chez #Amazon, on pisse dans une bouteille pour éviter des sanctions : Selon.. /Ul8sMwX1T6 /TZ7WVF1HOP&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @kurodorifunny: ????????????2?????? #RT??????\n??10??? #Amazon???? 1000??????\n\n?????2??\n?2000RT?4?\n?3000RT?6?\n?4000RT?8?\n?5000RT?10?\n\n????…&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Quantum Field Theory /aUHJorhZ1c #Amazon&#39;} 

&quot;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;5.0 Stars: Women&#39;s  Velvet Halter Dress for $129. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /K7n05rdqpb&quot;} 

&#39;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Better With You $25 Blog Tour Giveaway. Enter to win $25 from author Rachel John #Amazon #Paypal /MEOHSnnwRB&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;Dark Energy: Theory and Observations /573ji7vjAy #Amazon&#39;} 

&quot;, &quot;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &#39;RT @ATAGOofficial: ?\n#Amazon???? 1,000??????!!\n?\n\n1??????????\n? #????????????????????????????? ?\n\n??????\n@ATAGOofficial ????? &amp;amp; ???????RT\n?…&#39;} 

&quot;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;Before we all start thinking of conferring sainthood on #Amazon  because it&#39;s in 45&#39;s crosshairs, read this. And re… /akqRwVmWj0&quot;} 

&#39;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;#USA Deals: Women&#39;s Samantha  Wrap-front Handkerchief Dress for $148. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /kDZIVmD9xD&quot;} 

&#39;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;5.0 Stars: Women&#39;s Madalyn  Asymmetrical Faux-wrap Dress for $198. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /EnNeHOgVND&quot;} 

&#39;, &#39;{&#39;TweetText&#39;: &quot;4.4 Stars, 609 Reviews: Men&#39;s Big-tall  560 Comfort-fit Jean for $33. Great Deal for Today! #Monday #Amazon #Deal [… /njf82q8PUa&quot;} 

&#39;]}]
```

---

If i split it i get an object. But i want an array. How to convert this datatype here. Or do i need to follow any other approach?

Comment: Hi, as you're receiving a string build as a json object, have you tried to parse it ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse

Comment: Can you try `JSON.parse("{{ responseList }}")`

Comment: I tried: i am getting this error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1"

Comment: @RahulAnand That's not helping. Please provide more info to debug. Can you print the console output of `my_var` `console.log(my_var)` ? after the my_var variable declaration ?

Comment: @RajaSimon  editing question with output of console.log(my_var)

Comment: Did you tried using `{{ my_var|jsonify }}` ?

Comment: If i run this in HTML file i get the following error:"Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError ,Exception Value: Invalid filter: 'jsonify' And if i do this in my javascript file i get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"